# hive condition if id exist

Tags: flutter, box, flutter-hive

i use this code `putData` but it shown repeat, i want to show my data from database to hive.box,i just want: if there is same id or exist, it cannot store to hive.box database.if not same or exist it wil store to databse hive.box.

this is `getdata` from mysql database

```
 Future getAllData() async {
    await openBox();

    String url = "http://dhoido.com/sttt/tes/viewHive.php";

    try{
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      var _jsonDecode = jsonDecode(response.body);
      // setState(() {
      //   var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
      //   list = resBody;
      // });
      // box.clear();

      // if (box.get('id').exists ) {
        await putData(_jsonDecode) as List;
      // }
    } catch (SocketException) {
      print(SocketException);

    }
```

```
Future putData(data) async {
  
    for(var d in data) {

      d = TodoModel(
          id: d['id'],
          title: d['title'],
          detail: d['detail'],
          isCompleted: false
      );
      if(d != box.values.toList()){
        box.add(d);
      }
      else{
        box.clear();
      }
    }
```